# How to handle answers that just contain "no"

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I flag answers consisting only of “No” or “Yes”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110165/should-i-flag-answers-consisting-only-of-no-or-yes)

Assuming the correct answer to the question is

> No

What is the correct etiquette when seeing these answers in /review ?

Voting down doesn't like the right option (assuming the answer is correct) yet voting up doesn't right either as trust is placed on the user who answered the question that he knows what he is talking about (yet no information as to why was added)

One can also leave it in /review with the hope that someone with the expertise will edit the question with "why" it is no?

Comment: *Someone with duplicate-fu please find the dupe. Because there is one, I just don't know how to search with just "no" as the search query.*

Comment: Two words: downvote them.

Comment: They should explain *why* for it to be a good answer.

Comment: Here's one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110165/should-i-flag-answers-consisting-only-of-no-or-yes

Comment: And possibly related, the good old [Is "Don't do it!" a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

Comment: Along these lines, what about questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755449/deleting-git-repository-gitolite)? It's hard for me to determine if I should downvote, flag the answer, flag the question, or do nothing.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SX3JnUhTaE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps leave a comment for the user to add more info. I often phrase it as:

> If a prof had asked you this question in class, would he be happy with the answer you provided?

Comment: Most likely reply: "No."

Comment: @BilltheLizard :) I did manage to guilt-trip an undergrad on Quant.SE into actually fixing his answer with this line.

Comment: Impressive! I feel like if I tried this, it would only result in me receiving serial downvotes.

Comment: @PopularDemand Well, I'm also a moderator on Quant.SE, so I kind of have that authoritative vibe going.

Comment: [No](http://google.com/search?q=Austin%20Powers%20no&btnI=1)